# Select nodes in a Tree Control (MFC)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, treecontrol

I created a tree control in  VC++, but I cant select the child nodes. Any suggestions?

```
m_pTree->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP |
                 TVS_HASLINES | TVS_HASBUTTONS | TVS_LINESATROOT |
                 TVS_SINGLEEXPAND | TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | 
         TVS_TRACKSELECT,CRect(10, 10, 200, 240), this, 0x1221);

hTree=m_pTree->InsertItem(_T("SoftWare Production") , TVI_ROOT);
hCompany=m_pTree->InsertItem(_T("Microsoft"),hTree);
m_pTree->InsertItem(_T("Office") , hCompany);
m_pTree->InsertItem(_T("Visual Studio") , hCompany);
m_pTree->InsertItem(_T("Servers") ,hCompany , TVI_LAST);

m_pTree->Expand(hCompany, TVE_EXPAND);

hCompany=m_pTree->InsertItem(_T("Linux"),hTree);
m_pTree->InsertItem(_T("Open Office") , hCompany);
m_pTree->InsertItem(_T("QMail") , hCompany);
m_pTree->InsertItem(_T("Apache") ,hCompany,TVI_LAST);



m_pTree->Expand(hCompany, TVE_EXPAND);
```

Comment: select it programatically? show some code?

Comment: You have to edit your answer and paste the code. dont do it in comment

Comment: I need to select them when my program runs

Comment: Works fine for me. After running my application i am able to select the items using mouse

Comment: Really??? I cant do.. Only the Parent node is Selectable

Comment: what application is it MFC? Dialog/SDI?

Answer (score 1):

I think m_pTree->SelectItem(HTREEITEM) should work